# Special characters not displaying on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, character-encoding, hex, special-characters, non-ascii-characters

[Last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67692660/composer-error-deploying-laravel-application-on-elasticbeanstalk) I facing some difficulties when deploying an app to amazon web services and after spending hours I found out that one of my problems was that my code had some special characters not showing on vscode.

Today my code was not working again, this is the error I was getting:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'company_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `company_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (John Doe, john@biotrop.com.br, $2y$10$MZQPgxkC2fd5MXC4mIy5k.6rnHUj.FxQn1EsiVOZv13Jci6jqjiy2, 1, 2021-06-01 13:00:34, 2021-06-01 13:00:34))
```

When I opened the code on sublime, that same problem:

[image]

My question is: is there a way or extension available that make it possible to see those characters on vscode?

Comment: Does the setting `Render Control Characters` help?

Comment: @Mark  nope! Already tried that